# How to allow multiple values on a civicrm contextual filter in drupal views

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, drupal-views

I have a drupal view that shows aggregated totals  grouped by user from civi contribution pages.

The view has a contextual filter that takes the contribution page id as an argument.

The view works well if I pass in one argument.

I would like to be able to pass in multiple arguments, so, display contributions from contribpageID1 AND contribpageID2.

On contextual filters with drupal fields I am able, in the "more section", to select "Allow multiple values". This option isn't available on the `CiviCRM Contributions: Contribution Page` field.

Is this a limitation of the civi views integration? Or a setting I can't find.

Below is the query being run:

`SELECT SUM(civicrm_contribution.total_amount) AS civicrm_contribution_total_amount
FROM 
{civicrm_contribution} civicrm_contribution
WHERE (( (civicrm_contribution.contribution_page_id = '12') )AND(( (civicrm_contribution.financial_type_id IN  ('1')) AND (civicrm_contribution.contribution_status_id IN  ('1')) AND (civicrm_contribution.is_test = '0') AND (civicrm_contribution.receive_date >= '2014-12-31 00:00:00') AND (civicrm_contribution.receive_date <= '2015-12-31 00:00:00') )))
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

On line 5, I want it to say ...`_page_id = '12,15')`...

Aggregation is turned on but the option is not there when this is turned off either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation in CiviCRM views implementation.

If you are a developer and know views api, i encourage you to propose a patch for this. You can find all the code in `drupal/modules/views/civicrm.views.inc` or `https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal`

More precisely, the function `civicrm_views_get_argument` return a `views_handler_argument_numeric` for all numeric data type. You might want to try changing that to `views_handler_argument_many_to_one`. But it's really a guess : i don't know if it will work and even less if it will work for every fields.

Otherwise, still with some programming knowledge, you could do a drupal module that implements [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) but it's more a drupal question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @samuelsov for your response. Knowing it doesn't currently do this helps me from going around in circles.  

Unfortunately my dev knowledge wouldn't stretch to creating a patch for this.  

I will take a look at the module option and also chat to our contract developer about creating that patch and whether we can fund it if it isn't too much.  

Thanks again