# Drupal contextual filters and Civi Arrays

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm trying to work out how to use a Drupal contextual filter on a Civi field that holds an array. So the filter seems like it can search for `table.field = 'value1'` and it can search for `table.field IN ('value1','value2')`

However, when I look at the field in the database it is structured like this `[]Value1[]Value2[]` - I'm using brackets here because I can't figure out how to make the square SOH symbol appear that is actually in the database.

So if I'm passing Value1 in the URL to the view, it only works when Value1 is all on its own, never when it is in a list/array of multiple values.

What it *seems* like I need to do is to have the contextual filter use the LIKE operator instead, but 1) that might not be ideal either, and 2) I don't see how to do that!

I did find this similar question from 2015, but it is not exactly the same, and I'm not sure if it is still accurate:
[How to allow multiple values on a civicrm contextual filter in drupal views](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/690/how-to-allow-multiple-values-on-a-civicrm-contextual-filter-in-drupal-views)

Am I overlooking something obvious for making this work? If not, any suggestions on how to get it working?